# python print 3 first elements of list in reverse mode

Tags: python, list

suppose i have a list like this:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5] # range(5)
```

i want to print this:

```
[2,1,0]
```

my python script is:

```
print(my_list[2:-1:-1])
```

but it **prints an empty list!**

is this a bug in python(2 and 3!)?

i wont use any trick like:

```
num_of_elems_i_want = 3
print(my_list[::-1][len(my_list) - num_of_elems_i_want:])
```

or third party modules..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could slice the `list` as shown:

```
print(my_list[2::-1])      # L[start:end:step]
```

**EDIT :**

The result that you had obtained is not a *Bug*.

Remember that traversal of the `list` elements takes place from left to right and there are no elements till `end=-4`[*viz* *elements*: 5 → 0 → 1 → 2] from `start=2`. So, an *empty* `list` is returned as a result.

For the same reason, you could also do `print(my_list[2:-7:-1])`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question (whether the result of the original is a bug).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Novice programmers with questions often assume that there is a bug in the language when they are _certain_ their code is right. In reality, it is _never_ a bug in the language

Answer (score 1):

You can also invert your list permanently for other uses:

```
my_list.reverse()
print(my_list[-4:-1])
```